# מֵאַבְנֵי (Gen. 28:11) and הָאֶבֶן (Gen. 28:18)

Tags: number, parshanut-torah-comment, vayeitzei

Do any commentaries mention a reason for the plural "stones" in Gen. 28:11 and the singular "stone" in Gen. 28:18?

In Gen. 28:11, it says that Ya'akov took "of the stones" (מֵאַבְנֵי) and put them for his pillows, while in Gen. 28:18 it says that he took the "stone" (הָאֶבֶן) that he put for his pillows.

Is there any significance to this change in number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rashi explains (translation from [chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8223/showrashi/true)) based on the Gemora in Chullin:

> He arranged them in the form of a drainpipe around his head because he
>   feared the wild beasts. They [the stones] started quarreling with one
>   another. One said, “Let the righteous man lay his head on me,” and
>   another one said, “Let him lay [his head] on me.” Immediately, the
>   Holy One, blessed be He, made them into one stone. This is why it is
>   stated (verse 18):“and he took the stone [in the singular] that he had
>   placed at his head.” [From Chullin 91b]

However, others (Ibin Ezra, [Radak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40230&st=&pgnum=122), Ralbag, Zohar Chadosh 27b and see Tosfos to Chullin 91b) note that there is no contradiction at all. 28:11 states "מאבני" - "**of the** stones" and not "אבני" - "stones", and could therefore be explained that he took one of the stones that were there.

Comment: Ah yes, good point in your edit. Quick question, where did you find Radak's meforash on Bereshit, or even the Torah? This site only begins at Yehoshu'a: http://www.daat.ac.il/he-il/tanach/parshanut_hamikra/full-text/radak. Thanks.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 The Radak is quoted in Torah Shleima (footnote 60). It's probably somewhere on hebrewbooks.org, if I have time I will try link to it.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/40230

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Torath Hyim by Mosad HaRav Kook has RaDa"K's commentary on the Torah.